# Update a csv file using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a csv file, with student name and marks. I want to update "marks" of a student with name "jack"(the only person in the csv). the data in csv file looks as below.

```
student,marks
jack,10
peter,20
rick,10
```

I found this awk '$1 == "Audrey" {print $2}' numbers.txt, but iam not sure on how to modify the file.

Comment: The traditional (and most correct) approach is: `awk ... numbers.txt > output && mv output numbers.txt` or similar.

Comment: I would use sed: `sed -i 's/jack,.*/jack,12/g' numbers.txt` where 12 is the new mark

Comment: Thank you Andres, but i get the error sed: 1: "input.csv": command i expects \ followed by tex

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $1=="jack"{$2=27} 1' foo.csv > tmp && mv tmp foo.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with

```
sed -ir "s/^\(jack\),.*/\1,$new_grade/"
```

input.csv. with argument "r" or else i get the "*error sed: 1: "input.csv": command i expects \ followed by text*".

Comment: Your version of sed apparently requires `-i` to take an argument. Just use awk.

Answer (score 1):

`ed` is usually better for in-place editing of files than `sed`:

```
printf "%s\n" "/^jack,/c" "jack,${new_grade}" "." w | ed -s input.csv
```

or using a heredoc to make it easier to read:

```
ed -s input.csv <<EOF
/^jack,/c
jack,${new_grade}
.
w
EOF
```

At the first line starting with `jack,`, **c**hange it to `jack,XX` where `XX` is the value of the `new_grade` variable, and **w**rite the new contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed:

```sh
new_grade=9
sed -i'' "s/^\(jack\),.*/\1,$new_grade/"
```

The pattern `^\(jack\),.*` matches the beginning of the line `^` followed by `jack` by a comma and the rest of the line `.*`. The replacement string `\1,$new_mark` contains the first captured group `\1` (in this case `jack`) followed by a comma and the new mark.

Alternatively you could loop over the file and use a pattern substitution:

```sh
new_grade=9
while read -s line; do
    echo ${line/jack,*/jack,$new_grade}
done < grades.txt > grades2.txt
```

Comment: thank you @Serigo can this be done using a bash script? or awk?

Comment: but this command should update my csv file, this just prints the updated file?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with `sed` is to anchor the replacement to the digits at the end of the line with:

```
sed '/^jack,/s/[0-9][0-9]*$/12/' file
```

This uses the form `sed '/find/s/match/replace'` where `find` locates at the beginning of the line `'^'` the word `"jack,"` eliminating all ambiguity with, e.g. `jackson,33`. Then the normal *substitution* form of `'s/match/replace/'` where `match` locates at least one digit at the end of the line (anchored by `'$'`) and replaces it with the `12` (or whatever you choose).

**Example Use/Output**

With your example file in `file`, you would have:

```
$ sed '/^jack,/s/[0-9][0-9]*$/12/' file
student,marks
jack,12
peter,20
rick,10
```

(**note:** the POSIX character class of `[[:digit:]]` is equivalent to `[0-9]` which is another alternative)

The equivalent expression using the POSIX character class would be:

```
sed '/^jack,/s/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*$/12/' file
```

You can also use *Extended Regular Expression* which provides the `'+'` repetition operator to indicate *one-or-more* compared to the basic repetition designator of `'*'` to indicate *zero-or-more*. The equivalent ERE would be `sed -E '/^jack,/s/[0-9]+$/12/' file`

You can add the `-i` option to edit in-place and/or using it as `-i.bak` to create a backup of the original with the `.bak` extension before modifying the original.